# Exception in Worker Process When Running "heroku local"

Tags: python, mysql, heroku

I recently acquired a project that I am using heroku to build. I want to run it locally however I am running into trouble and I don't have much experience with Heroku. This is what I get when I try to run heroku local.

Mac Terminal Command

```
kaMacintosh:zddev ka$ heroku local
forego | starting web.1 on port 5000
web.1  | [2015-12-26 15:12:43 -0500] [1741] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 19.4.1
web.1  | [2015-12-26 15:12:43 -0500] [1741] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:5000 (1741)
web.1  | [2015-12-26 15:12:43 -0500] [1741] [INFO] Using worker: sync
web.1  | [2015-12-26 15:12:43 -0500] [1744] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 1744
web.1  | [2015-12-26 15:12:43 -0500] [1744] [ERROR] Exception in worker process:
web.1  | zd/main.py", line 6, in <module>
web.1  | ka/Documents/zdenvs/zddev/main.py", line 6, in <module>
web.1  | [2015-12-26 15:12:43 -0500] [1744] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 1744)
web.1  | Traceback (most recent call last):
web.1  |     sys.exit(run())
web.1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 74, in run
web.1  |     super(Application, self).run()
web.1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 72, in run
web.1  |     Arbiter(self).run()
web.1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 179, in run
web.1  |     self.manage_workers()
web.1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 482, in manage_workers
web.1  |     self.spawn_workers()
web.1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 549, in spawn_workers
web.1  |     time.sleep(0.1 * random.random())
web.1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 219, in handle_chld
web.1  |     self.reap_workers()
web.1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 464, in reap_workers
web.1  |     raise HaltServer(reason, self.WORKER_BOOT_ERROR)
web.1  | gunicorn.errors.HaltServer: <HaltServer 'Worker failed to boot.' 3>
```

Procfile

```
web: gunicorn main:app --log-file=-
```

It appears line 6 is the issue which is mysql.connector, here are the first several lines to main.py

main.py

```
import os
import sys
import json
import urllib
import custom
import mysql.connector
import datetime
import operator

from flask import Flask, jsonify
from flask import render_template
from flask import request, redirect, url_for
from mysql.connector import errorcode
application = Flask(__name__)
app = application
```

Any ideas as to what is causing the error or how to solve. Is it really mysql.connector causing the issue on line 6 in main.py? I am using Python 2.7.11.

Running `gunicorn main:app` on its own produces

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 515, in spawn_worker
    worker.init_process()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 122, in init_process
    self.load_wsgi()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 130, in load_wsgi
    self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
    self.callable = self.load()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 65, in load
    return self.load_wsgiapp()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 52, in load_wsgiapp
    return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 354, in import_app
    __import__(module)
  File "/Users/ka/Documents/zdenvs/zddev/main.py", line 6, in <module>
    import mysql.connector
ImportError: No module named mysql.connector
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 515, in spawn_worker
    worker.init_process()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 122, in init_process
    self.load_wsgi()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 130, in load_wsgi
    self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
    self.callable = self.load()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 65, in load
    return self.load_wsgiapp()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 52, in load_wsgiapp
    return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 354, in import_app
    __import__(module)
  File "/Users/ka/Documents/zdenvs/zddev/main.py", line 6, in <module>
    import mysql.connector
ImportError: No module named mysql.connector
[2016-01-04 15:34:18 -0500] [6225] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 6225)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/gunicorn", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(run())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 74, in run
    WSGIApplication("%(prog)s [OPTIONS] [APP_MODULE]").run()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 192, in run
    super(Application, self).run()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 72, in run
    Arbiter(self).run()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 179, in run
    self.manage_workers()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 482, in manage_workers
    self.spawn_workers()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 549, in spawn_workers
    time.sleep(0.1 * random.random())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 219, in handle_chld
    self.reap_workers()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 464, in reap_workers
    raise HaltServer(reason, self.WORKER_BOOT_ERROR)
gunicorn.errors.HaltServer: <HaltServer 'Worker failed to boot.' 3>
```

Comment: do you have a mysql connector installed?

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not have any answer, but I am having the same issue (able to run remotely and unable to run the app locally). My error is

`web.1  | [2015-12-31 17:59:51 -0400] [4100] [ERROR] Exception in worker process:`
`web.1  | le>`
`web.1  | "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 357, in import_app`

Comment: Yes, I am using it for other products. I am using aws for database though, I don't know if that could be causing the issue.

Comment: Can you run `gunicorn main:app` by itself without the heroku wrapper?

Comment: I just updated. It has something to do with mysql database connector import not found, I don't quite know how to fix since I am not too familiar with python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was an issue with the mysql-connector-python library. It was abandoned midway through my project, so it was on installed on the heroku instance but not on my local machine. Instead I just replaced the this line in the requirements.txt file:

```
mysql-connector-python==2.0.4
```

with

```
https://cdn.mysql.com/Downloads/Connector-Python/mysql-connector-python-2.0.4.tar.gz
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to run manually

"python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:5000"

Comment: You could improve your answer by adding information on what it does, how it helps and by adding reference.